# How to set a speed limit for a speedometer Android app?

Tags: java, android

For my regions science fair, I am making a speedometer app for Android and I want to set a speed limit. Here is the code I'm having trouble with:

```
     public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    TextView txt = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);


    if (location==null)
    {
        txt.setText("-.- km/h");
    }
    else if (location == 1.50)
    {
        txt.setText("Warning");
    }
    else 
    {
        float nCurrentSpeed = location.getSpeed();
        txt.setText(nCurrentSpeed*3.6 + " km/h");
    }

}
```

I want to make it so that when the speed 1.50 km/h it changes the text to "Warning". I keep getting `Incompatible operand types Location and double`. I have tried doing this

```
    else if (nCurrentSpeed == 1.50)
{
    txt.setText("Warning");
}
```

But it still gives me the same error, but modified `Incompatible operand types float and double`. Is there any tips on how to solve this or how to create a speed limit for a speedometer?

Comment: compare with a float like this: if (nCurrentSpeed == 1.50f) but don't you want to use >= instead of ==?

Comment: 1.5 is double,  1.5f is float.  I still don't understand why you are comparing objects with primitives though.

Comment: Also, never use == with floats or doubles.  Its extremely, extremely rare that a value with any math done on it will be exact in the floating point world.  Decide on a reasonable amount the answer could be off by, and check if the answer is in that range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `location` object is not just a primitive object, but its contents is not know here.

However based upon later code, you are showing that it has

```
location.getSpeed()
```

so change your code to

```
else if (location.getSpeed() == 1.50)
```

I would also suggest that you use `>= 1.5`

Comment: Thank you both Scary Wombat and gts 101 for your answers. I'm new to programming so I'm a bit oblivious to this sort of thing!

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't it just be something like

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    TextView txt = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);


    if (location==null)
    {
        txt.setText("-.- km/h");
    }
    else if (location.getSpeed() >= 1.50f)
    {
        txt.setText("Warning");
    }
    else 
    {
        float nCurrentSpeed = location.getSpeed();
        txt.setText(nCurrentSpeed*3.6 + " km/h");
    }

}
```

i.e. you need to compare location.getSpeed() with 1.5, not the whole location Object